# ODOO10CE export attachments to ODOO14CE

Tags: odoo, odoo-10, odoo-14

I have the `ODOO10CE` with many PDF attachments. Most are linked to accounting entries and invoices.

Can someone recommend me how to transfer them to `ODOO14CE` and re-link them to the accounting entries and invoices?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have already successfully upgraded your database from 10 to 14 and the only thing still outstanding is your attachments, then you should simply move your filestore as you would move any set of folders.

It seems... unlikely... that you would have successfully upgraded from 10 to 14 without knowing this however so maybe there's more to the question than I'm seeing?

For general knowledge, check out the Odoo 14 Documentation on importing documents:

- https://www.odoo.com/documentation/user/14.0/general/base_import/import_faq.html

Comment: Thanks frozenjim. I usually do tests on other servers so that there are fewer problems when doing it in production and the part of accessing the files is what I do not see clear.
I have previously read the link you have sent me but it doesn't say anything about importing the attached files.

Comment: Depending on your setup, your attached files will be in either the FILESTORE - which is just a set of folders - or in the database itself.  So if you did migrate the database, and it is working just fine but you cannot see your attachments, then you probably just need to copy the old filestore over to the new server.